# Definition of expectation of measure on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, definition, expected-value

For a real-valued random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ and distribution $\mu$, the expectation is defined by

$$ E[X] := \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) ~ d \mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x ~ d \mu(x) $$

For Banach-space $E$ valued random variable with distribution $\mu$, the expectation is the linear functional $m: E^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$ m(f) = \int_E f(x) d \mu(x), ~~~ f \in E^{\ast} ~~.$$

Which makes $m$ and element of $(E^{\ast})'$ assuming it is even well defined to begin with. This coincides with the definition for the expectation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and one can also recover the definition for $\mathbb{R}$ as defined above.

However, a prior it is not clear (and in general false) that $m$ is representable by an element of $E$ i.e. $m = \text{ev}_a$ for some a \in E$.

However, for things like laws of large numbers this is something really desirable i.e. for $E$-valued iid random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ one would like to make statements about

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \rightarrow a $$

for some $n \in E$ akin to the expectation of $X_1$.

So why not define the expectation of a measure $\mu$ as

$$n = \int_{X} x ~ d \mu(x) $$

in the sense of Bochner?

For $E = \mathbb{R}^n$ the two notions agree since for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$ m(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle y,x \rangle d \mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_i d \mu(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_i d \mu(x) = \langle y, n \rangle $$

And it is generally true that (at least on Banach spaces), if the expectation in the sense of Bochner exists, that $m$ exists and is a bounded linear functional on $E^{\ast}$ represented by $n$:

$$ f(n) = f( \int_E x d \mu(x)) = \int_E f(x) d \mu(x) =: m(f) ~~$$

for any $f \in E^{\ast}$ since $f$ is bounded.

So my question is why not use the Bochner definition, or in other words, what can be gained by using this more general definition of expectation?

Comment: You may use the Bochner integral provided $x \mapsto x$ is $\mu$-Bochner integrable.  This must be proved.  For example, if the support of $\mu$ is separable and bounded.  That is, if there is a separable bounded set $A$ so that $\mathbb P[X \in A] = 1$.

Comment: Do you have an example of a situation in which this is not the case? How does one then formulate things like laws of large numbers?